# How to fix the internal server error 500 Undefined Index:" "? Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, eloquent

when I try to make this POST request I get an Internal Server Error status 500 and when I look at the detail it says `"message": "Undefined index: CWID",` Here's what I was trying to POST:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
0:
CRN: 345627
Course_Code: "CIS305"
Start_Date: "2020-01-21"
End_Date: "2020-05-08"
Course_Time: "15:30:00"
Days_Of_The_Week: "TTR"
Course_Term: "Spring 20"
CWID: "C38475920"
Date_Registered: "2020-04-02"
1:
CRN: 456392
Course_Code: "CIS341"
Start_Date: "2020-01-21"
End_Date: "2020-05-08"
Course_Time: "18:00:00"
Days_Of_The_Week: "W"
Course_Term: "Spring 20"
CWID: "C38475920"
Date_Registered: "2020-04-02"
2:
CRN: 612093
Course_Code: "CIS492"
Start_Date: "2020-01-21"
End_Date: "2020-05-08"
Course_Time: "12:30:00"
Days_Of_The_Week: "TTR"
Course_Term: "Spring 20"
CWID: "C38475920"
Date_Registered: "2020-04-02"
```

I'm posting into this table:

```
 protected $table ="final_schedule";
  public $timestamps = false;
  protected $fillable = [
    'CWID',
    'CRN',
    'Date_Registered'
  ];
```

Here's the function in my controller:

```
public function insert(Request $request){
    $array = [];
    foreach (request()->all() as $value) {
    array_push($array, [
      'CWID' => $value['CWID'], //This is part of the problem apparently
      'CRN' => $value['CRN'], 
      'Date_Registered' => $value['Date_Registered']]);
  }
    DB::table('final_schedule')->insert($array);
  }
```

That function posts the data using postman fine. I was using this data set in postman:

```
[
    {   
    "CRN": 345627,
    "Course_Code": "CIS305",
    "Start_Date": "2020-01-21",
    "End_Date": "2020-05-08",
    "Course_Time": "15:30:00",
    "Days_Of_The_Week": "TTR",
    "Course_Term": "Spring 20",
    "CWID": "C38475920",
    "Date_Registered": "2020-04-02"
    },
    {
    "CRN": 456392,
    "Course_Code": "CIS341",
    "Start_Date": "2020-01-21",
    "End_Date": "2020-05-08",
    "Course_Time": "18:00:00",
    "Days_Of_The_Week": "W",
    "Course_Term": "Spring 20",
    "CWID": "C38475920",
    "Date_Registered": "2020-04-02"
    },
    {
    "CRN": 612093,
    "Course_Code": "CIS492",
    "Start_Date": "2020-01-21",
    "End_Date": "2020-05-08",
    "Course_Time": "12:30:00",
    "Days_Of_The_Week": "TTR",
    "Course_Term": "Spring 20",
    "CWID": "C38475920",
    "Date_Registered": "2020-04-02"
    }
]
```

Comment: How you are calling method `insert` ? I think it because of `request()->all()`

Comment: just print_r(request()->all()) to see what datas you got , I think there are more data which for example is not type of array and doesn't has 'CWID' index

Comment: This is what I get if I print out $array `Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[CWID] => C38475920
[CRN] => 345627
[Date_Registered] => 2020-04-02
)

[1] => Array
(
[CWID] => C38475920
[CRN] => 456392
[Date_Registered] => 2020-04-02
)

[2] => Array
(
[CWID] => C38475920
[CRN] => 612093
[Date_Registered] => 2020-04-02
)

)`

Comment: Do you validate your request and validate the nested fields ```CWID```, ```CRN``` and ```Date_Registered``` as required?
If you say it worked using postman, what attempt is not working properly?